# VM engine that reuses installed OS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am running a tripple-booting MacBook Pro. It boots between Ubuntu, Mac and Win7 (likely going to drop Win10 on it asap).

Now I would like to do tasks in my Mac, my primary OS, while pulling updates for games and software in my Windows.

I have seen that Parallels allowed Mac users to start a virtual copy of their Windows to do exactly that kinda stuff. But since I have a tripple boot setup with quite a mix-and-mash setup, I likely need a bit of a custom solution.

My setup:

```
Ingwie@Ingwies-Macbook-Pro.local ~ $ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            819.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows HD              157.3 GB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         10.5 GB    disk0s4

Ingwie@Ingwies-Macbook-Pro.local ~ $ sudo gdisk /dev/disk0
Password:
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
```

My bootloader is rEFInd and Ubuntu is booted via EFI. Only the Windows needs to be booted in Legacy mode (= BIOS) due to Apple drivers appearently not working in EFI mode...

Which virtualization software would support me running my Windows from this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallels can use a Boot Camp Windows install as a virtual OS inside OS X - so long as you shut it down rather than suspend, when you've finished; otherwise it won't boot from Boot Camp next time.

Comment: You think it will work with the fact that my Windows is installed on a totally different partition?

Comment: Turns out it picked up my windows right away (using the trial). But it seems to not let me choose and always goes for `disk0s3`. Thanks for your info :)

Comment: I've never tried it on a triple-boot system. Mine finds it just fine, though, even on a completely different drive, once I've pointed it in the right direction.

Comment: I wasnt given an option really. It just configured and set up. But hey, its working the way I hoped. let's hope it doesn't break when I boot into it physically. :)